# Regular expression to match Amsterdam postcodes

Tags: javascript, regex

can any one tell me regular expression for postalcode of Amsterdam, Netherlands for validation
EX. 1113 GJ

Postal code format [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_in_the_Netherlands) (thanks to [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka)):

> 1011–1199 plus a literal suffix AA-ZZ,
>   e.g. 1012 PP

Comment: Can you provide a couple of example Amsterdam, NL postcodes?

Comment: According to Wikipedia 1011–1199 plus a literal suffix AA-ZZ, e.g. 1012 PP. @rajanikant you could at least put that little effort into your question and look it up yourself.

Comment: example of nl postalcode is 1113 GJ

Answer (score 5):

```
^(11[0-9]{2}|10[2-9][0-9]|101[1-9])\s*[A-Z]{2}$
```

will match numbers from 1011-1199, followed by two letters from A to Z.

Answer (score 0):

Edit after the Wikipedia definition was posted (nice one Pekka :) ):

```
1[0-1][0-9]{2} [A-Z]{2}
```

Comment: Matches some illegal numbers (like 1000).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
^(11[0-9]{2}|10[1-9]{2}|10[2-9]0)\s*([A-Z]{2}|[a-z]{2})
```

As the postalcode range of Amsterdam is from 1011, using 1[0-1][0-9]{2} will also cause the 1000 code to match. In this example the range 1000 - 1010 will not be matched.

This bit matches 1100 - 1199:

```
(^11[0-9]{2})
```

This bit matches 1011 - 1099, but does not match 1020, 1030, 1040 and so on:

```
(^10[1-9]{2})
```

This bit matches 1020 - 1090, in steps of 10, matching 1020,1030,1040 and so on:

```
(^10[2-9]0)
```